# calculate exponential integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^c\left(e^{-ax}- e^{-bx}\right)e^{-d/x}dx$$
and $0<a_1<b_1,d>0，c>0$.  How to calculate this integral? Or a lower bound of this integral?

Comment: So you have
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int_0^c\left(e^{-ax}- e^{-bx}\right)e^{-d/x}dx \\
  &= \int_0^c e^{-ax - d/x}dx - \int_0^c e^{-bx - d/x}dx \\
  &= f(a,c,d) - f(b,c,d),
\end{split}
$$
which reduces the problem to finding
$$
f(a,c,d) = \int_0^c e^{-ax - d/x}dx
$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I failed in solving this sub-problem. It is integrable but the exact expression may be hard to derive. Hence, I am looking for a lower bound of the original problem.